# Cannot do Impersonation in Office365 EWA

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to do Impersonation in Office365 EWS, but when I try to send the request I receive this error.

"The account does not have permission to impersonate the requested user."

This is the piece of code about Impersionation

```
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "account2@example.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

That particular error means the users your using hasn't been granted the Application Impersonation rights to the user you trying to access see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722376(v=exchg.150).aspx